# Style a part of text in vue.js, when using a slot-scope

Tags: vue.js

This is how I'm showing the text in an Element-ui table

```
<el-table>
    <el-table-column
        label="Accion">
        <template slot-scope="scope">
            {{formatModel(scope.row.subject_type) + ': ' + scope.row.description }}
        </template>
    </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

Is there a way to make this part `formatModel(scope.row.subject_type)` be bold or a different color from the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your string concatenation up, and put the text that you want in between `<strong>` tags:

```
<template slot-scope="scope">
    <strong>{{ formatModel(scope.row.subject_type) }}</strong>:
    {{ scope.row.description }}
</template>
```